# Haskell error: non-exhaustive patterns in function

Tags: haskell

i was trying to made a function to verify if a Node exists in a list (i'm working with graphs):

```
buscaNodo :: [(Nodo,Peso)]->Nodo->Bool
buscaNodo _[] = False
buscaNodo ((a,b):ar) n 
        |(n == a)= True || (buscaNodo ar n)
        |(n /= a)= False || (buscaNodo ar n)
        |otherwise = False
```

That function returns me a true always that the node exists in the list; but if it doesn't exists in the list haskell show me an error : Non-exhaustive patterns in function buscaNodo, i need some help please, i was learning haskell recently and dont have the neccesary knowledge for solve that problems by myself. I'm so sorry for my dreadful english. Thank you for all

Comment: Can you provide the definitions of `Nodo`, `Peso`, and the error message you get?  These bits of information make it much easier to figure out what the actual problem you have is.

Comment: Also, I would suggest using higher level functions to solve this problem.  If all you need to do is find if `n` is in that list, then you can do so quite easily with a combination of `map fst` and `elem`, such as `buscaNodo graph n = elem n $ map fst graph`.  This doesn't solve the error you're getting, but it would be an alternate solution to what you're trying to do.

Comment: 'Nodo' is only a 'String' . 'Peso' is a duple of '(Int,Float)'. In this function i dont use 'Peso', i only want to know if a String exists in a list. But when it doesnt exists, appears the error: 'Non-exhaustive patterns in function buscaNodo'

Comment: Looks like the argument order is wrong in one of the first equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is exactly because of the definition for `type Nodo = String`.  Since `String` itself is a list of `Char`s, this means that when you have the pattern

```
buscaNodo _ [] = False
```

This is equivalent to

```
buscaNodo _ "" = False
```

You're actually matching on the empty string.  What you probably meant was to have these arguments switched:

```
buscaNodo [] _ = False
```

Where looking up any element (`_`) on an empty list will always return `False`.

You can also greatly simplify this definition by using built-in functions that come with Haskell:

```
buscaNodo :: [(Nodo, Peso)] -> Nodo -> Bool
buscaNodo graph node = elem node $ map fst graph
```

And now you don't have to worry about any cases at all.

Comment: it really works, i have too much to learn of haskell. I understand more of it. thank you for that recommendation

Comment: @RayMontiel It can be hard to grasp Haskell at first, but actually your solution is nothing more than a specialized version of the implementation I gave. If you were to look at the definitions for `map` and `elem`, you'd see a striking resemblance between them (particularly `elem`) and your code. What you wrote wasn't wrong, just more work than necessary thanks to the built-ins Haskell comes with. You certainly were on the right path, although some simplifications could have been made in your boolean logic, namely `n == a = True` and `n /= a = buscaNodo ar n`, and the `otherwise` is redundant.

Answer (score 4):

You have two cases for your `buscaNodo` function.  One is when the second argument is the empty string.  The other is when the first argument is a non-empty list.

But what about the case when both the first argument is an empty list and the second is a non-empty string?  When the function is called with the first argument empty and the second argument non-empty, neither of the two definitions fits.  Thus you get a non-exhaustive pattern error.